# Kindly suggest how to pass null parameter in between of route

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new in dotnet. Kindly suggest how to pass null parameter within the route.
My code is working for below routes:
https://localhost:7242/WeatherForecast/1/1/1
https://localhost:7242/WeatherForecast/1/1/
https://localhost:7242/WeatherForecast/1/

but not working for below URL, I am getting 404 error.
https://localhost:7242/WeatherForecast/1//1

It was working fine in .net4.5 but not working in 6.0

```
[HttpGet("{id}/{p1?}/{p2?}")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get(int id, int? p1 = 0, int? p2 = 0){
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]}).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You cannot have optional parameters in the middle of route. The route engine could only map the last optional parameter.  So you could only use the querystring instead of the friendly url could solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your route to accept these parameters as query strings.

In ASP.NET 6.0, there was a change in how route parameters are handled. The default behaviour of route parameters in ASP.NET 6.0 does not allow empty or null values.

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get(int id, int? p1 = null, int? p2 = null){
    // Your code here
}
```

This will allow routes like these to work

```
https://localhost:7242/WeatherForecast/1?p1=1&p2=
https://localhost:7242/WeatherForecast/1?p1=&p2=1
https://localhost:7242/WeatherForecast/1?p1=&p2=
```